# How to override the generate_filename function of a file name field in the parent class?

Tags: django, django-models

I have an abstract class `BaseFile` and a descendant `SeamlessFile`. In `SeamlessFile`, I override the `generate_filename` method of the `BaseFile`. Everything works flawlessly. Now if I want a descendant of `SeamlessFile`, and I want to override **only** the `generate_filename` method, this doesn't work, because my wild guess is that `generate_filename` associated with the `actual_file` is the one of `SeamlessFile`. It's ok I understand the problem, but I dont know how to solve it: how to override the `generate_filename` function of the parent (it's not only override, it's "make the `actual_file` model use the new function")?

```
class BaseFile(UidMixin, BaseModel):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    upload_directory = ""

    def generate_filename(self, filename):
        return "uploads/"


class SeamlessFile(BaseFile):
    def generate_filename(self, filename):
        return os.path.join("seam/", basename(filename))

    actual_file = models.FileField(
        default=None, null=True, blank=True,
        upload_to=generate_filename,
    )


class FrontEndAuditFile(SeamlessFile):
    def generate_filename(self, filename):
        print("FrontEndAuditFile -> generate_filename")
        return os.path.join("fro/", basename(filename))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `models.FileField` is called at the time of class creation, and hence you have already passed it the `generate_filename` declared at that point, and inheriting won't change anything. What you can do instead is to just use an extra method that will call the method on the class:

```py
class BaseFile(UidMixin, BaseModel):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    upload_directory = ""
    
    def _generate_filename(self, filename):  # Will call the actual method that returns the upload path
        return self.generate_filename(filename)
    
    def generate_filename(self, filename):
        return "uploads/"


class SeamlessFile(BaseFile):
    def generate_filename(self, filename):
        return os.path.join("seam/", basename(filename))

    actual_file = models.FileField(
        default=None, null=True, blank=True,
        upload_to=BaseFile._generate_filename,  # need to refer it as `BaseFile._generate_filename` because it is not defined in this scope (Will get added to class when it is actually made
    )


class FrontEndAuditFile(SeamlessFile):
    def generate_filename(self, filename):
        print("FrontEndAuditFile -> generate_filename")
        return os.path.join("fro/", basename(filename))
```

Comment: It's a bit hacky, but not your fault, it's Python / Django itself, thanks for the answer!